# How to assign specific value to events in a Dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following data.

```
DOY  <- c(1:30) #Day of Year
rain <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.5,15.5,20.1,10.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7.6,19.2,44.5,3.4,5.5,0,0,0,0,0,0)
DF <- data.frame(DOY=DOY,rain=rain)
```

I am only interested in days, when it is raining, the rainfall events.

```
DF <- DF[DF$rain > 0,]
```

Output of `df`, which are the rainfall events:

```
DOY rain
8   5.5
9   15.5
10  20.1
11  10.4
20  7.6
21  19.2
22  44.5
23  3.4
24  5.5
```

In my example I have two rainfall Events. If it's not raining on consecutive days, it is always a new event. 
 Now I want to assign to each rainfall event an `ID`. Something like this is my expected output.

```
DOY rain ID
8   5.5  1
9   15.5 1
10  20.1 1
11  10.4 1
20  7.6  2
21  19.2 2
22  44.5 2
23  3.4  2
24  5.5  2
```

Comment: `DF$ID = c(1, 1+ cumsum(diff(DF$DOY) != 1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
cumsum(+c(TRUE, diff(DF$DOY) > 1))
```