# Remove rows in dataframe, which are not consecutive

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My question is [related to my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268103/how-to-assign-specific-value-to-events-in-a-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment104743786_59268103) but it's not quite the same.

Assuming I have this:

```
DOY  <-c (1:30) # Day of Year
rain <-c (0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,20,10,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,20,45,5,2,0,0,0,10,0,0)
DF <- data.frame(DOY=DOY, rain=rain)
# Just interested in days with rain
DF <- DF[DF$rain > 0,] 
# assign ID for each rainfall event, but only if Difference in days is >4
DF$ID <-c (1,1+cumsum(diff(DF$DOY) > 4)) 

# Rerranging, so I have the highest value at top for each group
DF <- DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(desc(rain),.by_group=TRUE)
```

My `DF` looks like this:

```
DOY rain    ID
10    20     1
 7    10     1
11    10     1
 9     9     1
12     5     1
22    45     2
21    20     2
28    10     2
20     5     2
23     5     2
24     2     2
```

But only want days which are consecutive from the day of max value. My expected output should then be:

```
DOY rain    ID
10    20     1
11    10     1
 9     9     1
12     5     1
22    45     2
21    20     2
20     5     2
23     5     2
24     2     2
```

Rows with DOY = 7 and DOY 28 should be removed in my case, all other DOYs are kept.

Comment: the third row is not consecutive

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "days which are consecutive from the day of max value"? To me, the day of max value is DOY==22 (rain==45) so you should keep only DOY==20 and DOY==22, which seems not what you want. Your post is well done with a reproducible example, but your expected output is unclear.

Comment: @TiltingTrain - According to your example, you want to return sequences of consecutive DOYs for each id? E.g [9, 10, 11] for id=1, or [21, 22, 23, 24] for id=2? Could id=1 have two sequences [9, 10, 11] and [21, 22, 23]? Would you want to keep both?

Comment: @OttoKässi - Yes I want to return sequences of consecutive DOYs for each ID so [9,10,11,12] for ID=1 and [21,22,23,24] for ID=2. And the max value should be in this sequence too, thats why I sorted it by max value

Comment: @DanChaltiel - Does my last comment to OttoKässi maybe clarify what my expected Output should be?

Comment: Does each id have exactly one sequence?

Comment: @OttoKässi Yes, each ID should only have exactly one sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can reuse the answer from your other question here (which was quite a neat trick BTW).

```
DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(DOY,.by_group=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(
    max_rain = max(rain),
    i=cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(DOY)>1))
  ) %>%
  group_by(i, ID) %>%
  filter(any(rain==max_rain))
```

Basically, for each ID, you save the maximal rain and you create another ordering group ID (`i` here). You have to arrange by `DOY` for this to work.

Then, you just need to group by both ID and filter out all groups that do not contain the max rain value.

Comment: Thank you very much! I supposed that I had to make save the maximum rain somehow, but I always got stuck. Now this helps me a lot, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

```
DF %>% arrange(ID, DOY) %>% 
       group_by(ID) %>% 
       mutate(lDOY = lag(DOY)) %>% 
       slice(c(min(which(DOY - lDOY == 1) -1), which(DOY - lDOY == 1))) %>%
       select(-lDOY) %>%
       arrange(ID, -rain)
```

Here we first sort by day and ID, and use slice only keep observations where tge difference of adjacent DOYs is 1. The min() part in slice() is needed to retain first observation of each sequence. Finally, the output is sorted by id and rain.

Note that this works only if you have exactly one sequence for each id.

Comment: This one works too, and is exactly what I wanted, too. I forgot to say, that in the real end, to sort it again by DOI, but this can then easily be done with `group_by`.
And there is always exactly one sequence for one ID, so there shouldn't be trouble with that